# Idiom for stop being super nervous, stressed out and super alert?

Tags: idiom-request

Idiom for stop being super nervous, stressed out and super alert? Is there an idiom for this? I came up with:

> Drop your guard.

But it doesn't come as natural when you say it. Is there a more informal or a better more natural way to say to someone to relax and calm down and stop being super nervous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common one would probably be

> Chill out.

This is both informal and natural. Of course it's often likely to be poorly-received since it's not an instruction that's easy to follow.

It's common enough to have an [entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chill%20out) in Merriam-Webster.

That definition provides an alternative:

> Calm down.

That one is less informal but still completely natural. However it's not quite as apt if you want someone to lower their vigilance, rather than descend from a state of agitation or anxiety.

Note that the quotes in this answer *can* (**edit**: I incorrectly wrote *should*) end in a "!" rather than a "." but I find that doing that in conversational text (e.g. in a chat app) comes off as overly emphatic or imperious.

**EDIT**:

Another informal expression, which may sound patronising:

> Cool your jets.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but there's no technical requirement for those sentences to end in exclamation marks. Imperative sentences may end in periods.

Comment: Oh, I've been carrying around that false norm since high school, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***Take a pill***

It's less common than "chill out", and might be getting dated. It was more popular in the 80s and 90s. It refers to people taking pills to calm their anxiety.

Comment: I have seen (very often), 'Take a chill pill, Bill (or Jill, depending on gender)'.